# EF Core HasQueryFilter doesn't work with Count()

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have class `Employee` and child class 'User' with `IsActive` state. User has `IsActive` property. We use `HasQueryFilter(e => e.IsActive)` to prevent getting inactive user. When we trying call Count() it is returns all count ignoring HasQueryFilter.

```
class User
{
     ....
     public bool IsActive { get; set; };
}

class Employee 
{
     ...
     public User User{ get; set; };
}

...
Entity<User>(e => e.HasQueryFilter(x => x.IsActive));

...
context.Employees.Include(x => x.User).Count(); // Returns all count ignoring QueryFilter.
```

Comment: Are you sure? Check the generated SQL. Also, what version of EF core are you using? It makes a big difference.

Comment: @AluanHaddad
I am using EF Core 2.1.2. The SQL query is generated correctly, but when I call `Count()` it returns a different result.

Comment: I mean the SQL generated by `.Count()`.

Comment: I do not see any filter on Employee??

Comment: @AluanHaddad
how to do it?

Comment: @ErikEJ
Employee filtering based on User filter

Comment: You can try to use sql profiler to check the generated SQL @Dmitry

Comment: Also are you using code first or db first approach to generate your database context ?

Comment: @VihangaBandara this query from profiler, when I call `Count()`:
```select  count(*) from Employee```

Comment: @Dmitry That is not how query filters work! You must refer to User in your query https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

Comment: @ErikEJ, I fixed the example code (add Include) but the problem is not solved

Comment: I think User is optimized away in your "fixed" query - not needed.

Comment: @ErikEJ, I tried to call context.Employees.Include(x => x.User).ToList().Count and got expected result, but I think It's being work more slowly.

Comment: I think you are abusing the combination of required related entity and related entity filter. The "correct" behavior when using `ToList()` is more like a side effect of the implementation, so is the "incorrect" direct `Count()` call.

Comment: @Dmitry, where do you use `HasQueryFilter`? The query filter is applied in the `OnModelCreating` method, and will result in queries that reference the entity.

Comment: @Karney, yes, I am using filters in `OnModelCreating` method.

Comment: You say "The SQL query is generated correctly". So you should have seen that `User` isn't even part of the query. All you're asking for from EF's POV is a count of employees.

Comment: @GertArnold, I can't figure out why when we use context.Employees.Include(x => x.User).Where(x => x.User.IsActive).Count() it works correctly  it works correctly but doesn't work with query filter.

Comment: Why don't you add all this to your question? Show the LINQ queries you tried and the SQL queries they generate. All extra info is scattered over comments and each comment is ambiguous. Like, I don't understand "...it works correctly but (it) doesn't work with query filter". What is "it" here (2x)?